Build process failed on macOS Sonoma 14.5 using Visual Studio Code
First time posting on Stackoverflow.
I am trying to learn how to program in Flutter.
I am following Google's tutorial here
I tried the debug and run mode in Visual code studio. New to flutter and programming in general.
The debug console tells me the following:
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:macOS, arch:arm64, id:00006020-001208C00ED3C01E, name:My Mac }
{ platform:macOS, arch:x86_64, id:00006020-001208C00ED3C01E, name:My Mac }
/Users/username/Documents/Development/Flutter/namer_app/namer_app/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/namer_app.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Flutter Assemble' from project 'Runner')
** BUILD FAILED **
Error: Build process failed
What am I doing wrong here?
Code in full below (under lib/main.dart in the project explorer)
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyAppState(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Namer App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepOrange),
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  var current = WordPair.random();
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('A random idea:'),
          Text(appState.current.asLowerCase),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Edit: Update
So tried Richard's command but it didn't work for me.
I moved it to my home folder as it is outside my iCloud and is what was causing a codesign issue.
It now informs me:
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations: { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, id:00006020-001208C00ED3C01E, name:My Mac } { platform:macOS, arch:x86_64, id:00006020-001208C00ED3C01E, name:My Mac } Opt-in to secure coding explicitly by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState:.
The app does load now!

The posted message is actually a warning, the real error message should be somewhere before this one. Did you install xcode? Since you are on a mac, you will need xcode.


resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed* <-- this error indicates one or more of the files in the app bundle being codesigned has an extended file attribute. Codesign does not support attributes on any file in the bundle. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1940/_index.html  BTW, I have zero knowledge of Flutter.


I have installed Xcode 15.4.

Great! I think you should follow Flutter's official docs for setting up on a Macbook because it will be slightly different from Google's tutorial. https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos You can build android apps on your mac but it just takes some fiddling around with xcode to get started. Post here if you get stuck!

I agree with Richard Barber; run xattr -r <source_dir> to see what files have extended attributes.  You can clear them with xattr -d <attribute> <file>.

@tbold I have now updated my question

@RichardBarber I have now updated my question
